# Generate splitChunks name based on entry point

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

I have the following (shortened) webpack configuration:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: "./app/index.ts",
        admin: "./app/index-admin.ts"
    },
    ...,
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                commons: {
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                    name: "vendors",
                    chunks: "all"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result is that 3 files get generated:

- app.min.js
- admin.min.js
- vendors.min.js

My problem is that "vendors.min.js" gets generated once for both entry point. The idea behind this configuration is that both entry point will be quite the same but in "index-admin.ts", I'll reference additional library such as tinyMce or something.

Therefore, I'd like to have 4 files generated:

- app.min.js
- admin.min.js
- app.vendors.min.js
- admin.vendors.min.js

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume we have two files:

**index.js**

```
import 'jquery';
```

**index-admin.js**

```
import 'jquery';
import 'lodash';
```

For example, we want to use lodash only for admin part and split it from the main app. That's the possible solution:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: "./app/index.js",
        admin: "./app/index-admin.js",
    },
    optimization: {            
        splitChunks: {
            chunks: 'all', // enable default cache groups, also this value will be inherited by the child groups
            cacheGroups: {
                // vendors is a default group, here we're overriding its configuration
                vendors: {
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                    name: "vendors.common",
                    // when you define your own group, its priority is 0, so you need to reset it to the default (or simply a negative) value for vendors
                    priority: -10
                },
                vendorsAdmin: {
                    // could be replaced with a function for the more complex scenario `function (module, chunk)`
                    test: /[\\/]lodash[\\/]/,
                    name: "vendors.admin",
                    // disable minSize/maxSize/minChunks/maxAsyncRequests/maxInitialRequests policies for this group
                    enforce: true,
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

As a result, we get the following file structure:

- app.js
- admin.js
- vendors.admin.js (lodash **only**)
- vendors.common.js (jquery **only**)

As simple as that. But this solution can lead to a weird behavior later. For example, someone from your team references `lodash` from the application bundle. The bundle structure won't change after the build, but now the `app.js` depends on the `vendors.admin.js`. So, when webpack manifest will try to bootstrap your application, it will start waiting for the `vendors.admin.js` being loaded, but that will never happen.

The most robust and easy solution is [dynamic imports](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports) and I strongly recommend to consider it, instead of this solution. You will get a lot more control over your dependencies and will be able to split your code even more granular.

If you don't want to control the bundling process yourself, it looks like you can rely on the default splitting strategy. It will output the same result for my example as in the previous config.

```
optimization: {
    splitChunks: {            
        chunks: 'all'            
    }
}
```

Comment: I indeed considered this approach but came to the same conclusion as you. I'll have a look at dynamic import then. I thought it would have been possible to do something like `name: [name].vendors.min.js` that would create "app.vendors.min.js" and "admin.vendors.min.js" with everything inside but it does not seem feasible.

Comment: Is it really the only way to do so? I see some disadvantages in this solution... Indeed, it means that I have to specify "webpackChunkName" everywhere I use a library. Moreover, maybe I'll do some mistake and type once "lodash" and the next time "loadsh"... I'm not really keen on using this.

Comment: Hmm, you don't need to specify webpackChunkName, it's optional. Webpack will be able to generate an id for each chunk itself. Also, it would resolve situations, when you will provide two imports of the same module with different "webpackChunkName", you can check it.

Comment: BTW have you tried a default strategy? =) I added the corresponding configuration to the end of my answer.

Comment: I've been trying to get something similar working. The reason I need it to work this way is so that parts of the app are completely ring-fenced from the others. While this was perfectly possible with the old CommonsChunkPlugin, splitChunks makes it seemingly impossible. Updating every import to dynamic across an enterprise scale app just isn't viable.

I've been playing with something like this but it's not quite there yet:

lib: {
  name:   'app/js/lib',
  test(module, chunks) {
    return (
      chunks.some(chunk => ['entry/a', 'entry/b'].includes(chunk.name))
    );
  },
},